# Android Studio - File System Synchronization

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have been getting "File System Synchronization" dialog a lot lately in Android Studio(almost whenever I run Gradle build). It's so annoying because it blocks the IDE's UI for around 5-10 seconds. The project I am working on is a medium~big size project. Anyone else seeing that? How to speed up the file system synchronization or reduce the frequency of getting that dialog?

- Android Studio 4.2.
- IDE and Gradle heap size: 8096 MB
- Mac i9, SDD

[image]

Comment: Same with me. Did you find a solution sir?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. @HussienFahmy

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I installed iobit Uninstaller recently
I found it scans the file continually
I closed it permanently via Task Manager in my windows and the problem solved